# Inform someone about a hacked account

Tags: passwords, disclosure, facebook

I'm not a hacker but recently I was able to get someone's email password. I want to teach him a lesson to be careful when using internet and to pay attention to his passwords but I have some problems:

- I don't know him and can't contact him face-to-face.
- He doesn't check his emails( there are tons of unread messages ) so I can't send him a message.
- I don't want him to know my identity so I can't contact him on Facebook .

I was thinking of hacking his Facebook account and displaying "you've been hacked " message but I don't want to go into illegal stuff. But I just can't leave him like this: what if someone stole his account. He is very vulnerable. What do you suggest to do?

Comment: Ok guys no more unexplained downvotes please

Comment: What lesson would you like to teach the person? That you'd have no problems opening any mail addressed to him if you somehow gained access to it? That there are nosy people out there that believe they have the moral upper hand over slightly more naïve ones? If he doesn't even check his email account, have you considered he might not care, has died, or even did it intentionally? You're getting downvotes because it isn't illegal to use weak passwords or misplace them. But it is illegal to use them to gain access to none of your business that is still password protected, even if weakly so.

Comment: @TildalWave I want to teach him to be more careful about his passwords. And btw I already did something illegal so what should I do .

Comment: persoanally, id turn your computer off, sit in a corner and think hard about a) your question and b) what you've done. Vtc

Comment: @D3C4FF will I go to jail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest sending them an email - that is the full extent of your responsibilities as a good citizen.

And then delete your copy of their password.

In some jurisdictions you could already be considered to have breached rules or even laws. Don't now go and do something that will be illegal. Don't teach them a lesson; don't hack their facebook account; just send them an email to let them know they should change their password, and then leave it up to them.

Comment: Please read the question thoroughly : he doesn't check his email he will never read the message.

Comment: Then send him a message on facebook...

Comment: @LucasKauffman I don't want him to know my identity.

Comment: I did read the question thoroughly - if he doesn't read the email that is his problem, not yours.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Is sending a message still a good idea if I know he will never read it. Or should I not send it at all?

Comment: You don't know he will never read it. I know I have >1000 unread emails across my email accounts, but I read many hundreds a day. Is up to you. If it were me, I would not have used his password at all, and definitely not gone into his email account. I would probably have sent an email and left it at that.

Answer (score 3):

Most jurisdictions define computer crimes in terms of accessing systems to which you do not have legitimate access. Whether you gain that access by guessing the password or exploiting a web server loophole does not matter - you do not have a legitimate right to access the system, so if you access his Email accounts then it is illegal.

I would suggest, that you send an Email to him explaining what you have got.